# MPAndroidChart Weekly data

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

So I am trying to do a weekly chart with current weeks data vs previous weeks data using MPAndroidChart. I can do single bars just fine and everything lines up, but when I try to do multi bar groups it does the following.

[image]
Is there something else I need to be doing? I only have 2 bars per group for each day. Here is my current code:

```
BarData barDataPayments = new BarData(barDataSetCurrentWeek, barDataSetPrevWeek);
        barChartPayments.setData(barDataPayments);

        XAxis xAxisPayments = barChartPayments.getXAxis();
        xAxisPayments.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labelWeekdayNames));

        xAxisPayments.setYOffset(5);
        xAxisPayments.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxisPayments.setLabelCount(labelWeekdayNames.size());
        xAxisPayments.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxisPayments.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
        xAxisPayments.setDrawGridLines(false);

        float groupSpace = 0.08f;
        float barSpace = 0.03f;
        float barWidth = 0.2f;

        barDataPayments.setBarWidth(barWidth);
        barChartPayments.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
        barChartPayments.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(0 + barChartPayments.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace, barSpace) * 14);
        barChartPayments.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace);

        barChartPayments.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up having to do is manually set the data. It took a little tweaking to get it just how I wanted it, I am sure there is a more proper way, but so far this was the easiest way that I have currently found.

```
xAxisMiles.setYOffset(0); // <---- CHANGED TO ZERO
xAxisMiles.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxisMiles.setLabelCount(labelWeekdayNames.size());
xAxisMiles.setGranularity(1f);
xAxisMiles.setCenterAxisLabels(true); // <---- SET TO TRUE
xAxisMiles.setDrawGridLines(false);

//IMPORTANT *****
barDataPayments.setBarWidth(0.40f);
barDataPayments.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
barDataPayments.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(7);
barDataPayments.groupBars(0, 0.10f, 0.05f);
//***** IMPORTANT*/
```

Answer (score 0):

here I have a snippet it may help you,

```
BarData barData = new BarData();
                int i=10;
                for (ExpenseData expenseData : results) {
                    List<BarEntry> barEntryList = new ArrayList<>();
                    barEntryList.add(new BarEntry(i, (float) expenseData.getBalance()));
                    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntryList, expenseData.getCategory());
                    int rand = (int) (i*Math.random());
                    barDataSet.setBarBorderWidth(1);
                    barDataSet.setBarBorderColor(Color.rgb(rand,i*20,i));
                    barDataSet.setColor(Color.rgb(rand,i*20,i));
                    barData.addDataSet(barDataSet);
                    i+=10;
                }
                barChart.setData(barData);
```